# CSV from a form php

Tags: php, csv, overwrite

I'm a begginer in PHP and I want to get data from a form which contains a name,a comment and a name of a photo the user selects, and put it in a csv.But when i try to write the date, the data i already have in the csv is overwrited.So every time I only have one line in my csv with the newest data.

I want data to be introduced in a new csv line everytime the form is used like this:

```
Russel,Hello,Football.jpg
James,Bye,Coke.png
```

Instead of being overwrited like this:

```
James,Bye,Coke,png
```

This is what i tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST["nom"];
    $comment = $_POST['com'];
    $image = $_FILES['imag']['name'];
    $csvfile = 'fichero.csv';
    $fvisitas = fopen($csvfile, "c+");
    $lista = array(
       array($name, $comment, $image)
    );
    foreach ($lista as $campos) {
        fputcsv($fvisitas, $campos);
    }
    fclose($fvisitas);
}
```

Comment: You are creating the file every time you open it with the second parameter: "c+" - replace this with an "a" and data is appended to the file. For reference: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php -> have a look at the section "mode".

Comment: If you have a new question - please ask a new question. It is not helpful or respectful to the people who took the time to read and answer the asked question to have the question changed significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You should open your file with the append flag

```
  $fvisitas = fopen($csvfile, "a");
```

This will let you append lines instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `a+` mode.

For more about fopen modes refer to [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
$fvisitas = fopen($csvfile, "a+");
```